# Has the transaction behavior changed when a conflict occurred in firestore datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

I created new Google Cloud Platform project and Datastore.

Datastore was created as "Firestore in Datastore mode".

But, I think Firestore Datastore and Old Datastore behave differently if Conflict occurred.

e.g Following case.

```
procA: -> enter transaction -> get -> put -----------------> exit transaction
procB: -----> enter transaction -> get -> put -> exit transaction
```

Old Datastore;

- procB is Completed and data is updated.
- procA Conflict occured and data is rollbacked.

Firestore in Datastore mode;

- procB is waited before exit transaction until procA is completed.Then Conflict occured.
- procA Completed and data is updated.

Is it spec?
I cannot find document on Google Cloud Platform documentation.

Comment: @DanCornilescu The post you talked me is about "Conflict occure in spite of entityGr isn't same Gr in ndb".I think it is another topic.My result is using google-client library.Conflict is not occure if entityGr is not sameGr.

Comment: Exactly. There *shouldn't* be a conflict, yet reported behavior appears as if it there would be one. The explanation, once found, *might* apply to your case as well.

Comment: Are you using the [python2 ndb client](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/) or [cloud ndb](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3/migrate-to-cloud-ndb)?

Comment: Im using [python client library](https://googleapis.dev/python/datastore/latest/index.html).And GUI GCP console seems same behavior, I think.(get & put & sleep within transaction from client library, Then GUI edit is waiting.Old datastore is not wait.)

Comment: Good hint from GUI waiting - I think this indicates the behaviour change is from the datastore side, not the client side, so unrelated to the other post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been giving it some thought and I think the change may actually be intentional.

In the old behaviour that you describe basically the shorter transaction, even if it starts after the longer does, is successful, preempting the longer one and causing it to fail and be re-tried. Effectively this give priority to the shorter transactions.

But imagine that you have a peak of activity with a bunch of shorter transactions - they will keep preempting the longer one(s) which will keep being re-tried until eventually reaching the maximum retries limit and failing permanently. Also increasing the datastore contention in the process, due to the retries. I actually hit such scenario in my transaction-heavy app, I had to adjust my algorithms to work around it.

By contrast the new behaviour gives all transactions a fair chance of success, regardless of their duration or the level of activity - no priority handling. It's true, at a price - the shorter transactions started after the longer ones and overlapping them will take overall longer. IMHO the new behaviour is preferable to the older one.

Comment: Hi all, the difference is now documented here: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#transaction_locks

Comment: @JuanLara Read-only transactions - nice!

Comment: Thanks Dan and @JuanLara !! Really useful and helpful and documentation and thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you describe is caused by the chosen concurrency mode for Firestore in Datastore mode. The default mode is Pessimistic concurrency for newly created databases. From the [concurrency mode documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#concurrency_modes):

> Pessimistic
>
> Read-write transactions use reader/writer locks to enforce isolation
> and serializability. When two or more concurrent read-write
> transactions read or write the same data, the lock held by one
> transaction can delay the other transactions. If your transaction does
> not require any writes, you can improve performance and avoid
> contention with other transactions by using a read-only transaction.

To get back the 'old' behavior of Datastore, choose "Optimistic" concurrency instead ([link to command](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#change_concurrency_mode)). This will make the faster transaction win and remove the blocking behavior.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to take a look at the documentation [Transactions and batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions). On this documentation you will be able to find more information and examples on how to perform transactions with Firestore.

On it, you will find more clarification on the `get()`, `set()`,`update()`, and `delete()` operations.

I can highlight the following from the documentation for you, that is very important for you to notice when working with transactions:

- Read operations must come before write operations.
- A function calling a transaction (transaction function) might run more than once if a concurrent edit affects a document that the transaction reads.
- Transaction functions should not directly modify application state.
- Transactions will fail when the client is offline.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: The doc you pointed to refers to the Firestore Native mode, not Datastore mode (and I believe your answer, too). Not the same thing, see [Choosing between Native Mode and Datastore Mode](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore)

Comment: @gso_gabriel I know "How to use transaction".Because my code works fine in Old Datastore.My understood Datastore controll conflict according to "Snapshot Isolation".But Firestore in datastore mode is not follow that rules.

Comment: Hey @stack_user checking the documentation about [Isolation and Consistency](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#isolation_and_consistency) on Datastore mode, it seems that it uses Serializable Isolation and Transaction Isolation indeed. Could you check this one that I mentioned and confirm if your code is following was is here?

Comment: Yes, I knew the topic you teach.But Datastore isolation solution is snapshot isolation.It means first commit success, following commit is fail&retry, I think(and old datastore did that.)

Comment: The Isolation method used is Serializable on Datastore mode, as mentioned in the documentation. Snapshot is only used to keep the state of the data, in case something fails. Considering that, I would say that this behavior is expected.